# Save Text Attributed to Parse (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am creating a basic note taking though parse using Swift. I want to save and load the text color, size, and font as well as the regular text. I've gotten the "non-attributed" text to save, but nothing else. Here is my code:

NotesTableViewController.swift:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NotesTableViewCell

let object: PFObject = self.notObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

cell.masterCell?.text = object["title"] as? String
cell.masterTextLabel?.text = object["text"] as? String

return cell
```

addNoteTableController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.colorPicker.alpha = 0
self.fontPicker.alpha = 0

if (self.object != nil) {
    self.titleField?.text = self.object["title"] as? String
    self.textView?.text = self.object["text"] as? String
}else {
    self.object = PFObject(className: "Note")
    }
}

@IBAction func saveAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
self.object["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
self.object["title"] = self.titleField?.text
self.object["text"] = self.textView?.text

self.object.saveEventually { (sucess, error) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
    }else {
        print(error?.userInfo)
    }
}

self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

My goal is for the user to be able to apply the effect to the text, save it, and when they reload it, the effects will still be there. (Please see screen shot.)

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx8do.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert your attributed text to NSData and save it as a File on Parse. You can then download it from Parse again and convert it to attributed text:

```
// Convert to NSData
let nsdata = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(attributedString)

// Back to NSAttributedString
let attributedString = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(nsdata)
```

Comment: Ok... Can you show me exactly how I would put this in my code

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well It is quite straightforward. Have you read the Parse documentation on how to save a PFFile ??

Comment: I don't know how, even after I read the documentation. Can you please give me the code?